# Display unicode characters (emojies) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

I have a database with tweets such as "\U0001f374 Lunch. Had loads of meat..." -- that is, with emojies represented as unicode (\U0001f374 is the knife&fork emoji). In my Web app I fetch tweets using Ajax requests and want to display them.

No big deal, and I have it so far up and running that I can display the "raw" tweet strings with the unicode. However, I like to render the emojies. How can I do this in Javascript?

Comment: Use some the of the emoji libraries to convert the unicode to the emojies https://github.com/twitter/twemoji

Comment: If I understand correctly, this library replace the unicode string with images. While I might want to do this in the long run, at the moment I would go with native rendering by the browser.

Comment: Yup, there are other libraries also which use native rendering, i gave you only one example of such library.

Comment: Do you mean you are having problems making the character U+1F374 render in browsers? (ie font problem)... or do you mean you literally have a backslash and a capital U in the database content? This is not a standard escaping format, so if that's the case you will need to look at the script that fetches the tweets and puts them in the database. It's doing some ad-hoc encoding that might be in error.

Comment: What if you have the UTF-8 string for an emoji? How do you output it as a variable or a literal in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a notation like `\U0001f374` is undefined in JavaScript, you need to construct the character from it with your own code (or suitable library code). You could parse the Unicode number from the string and convert it to a pair of surrogate code points.

But if you are using JavaScript in the HTML (or XML) context, you could let the HTML (or XML) parser do the job. Just change the string (assumed to have 8 hex digits) to an HTML or XML character reference and make sure the result is parsed as markup:

```js
var sample = document.getElementById('in').value;
sample = sample.replace(/\\U([0-9a-f]{8})/gi, "&#x$1;");
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = sample;
```

```html
<input id=in size=40
       value="\U0001f374 Lunch. Had loads of meat...">
<div id=demo>To be replaced</div>
```